# Android 5 portrait app crashes when going to Recents and rotating

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-orientation, oncreateoptionsmenu, android-recents

The activities of my app have all the attribute to make them portrait:

```xml
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

The minSdkVersion of the app is 21. With Android 5.0 phones the app crashes if the device is using the autorotate setting and the app goes to background (Recents/Overview screen) and then the device is rotated.

When this happens, this is the stacktrace I get from the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ActionMenuView.onConfigurationChanged(ActionMenuView.java:133)
        at android.view.View.dispatchConfigurationChanged(View.java:9487)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1294)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateConfiguration(ViewRootImpl.java:3417)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3599)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The problem seems to be in the onCreateOptionsMenu. This is the reduced version of my main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_mainpages, menu)
        val menuItem = menu.getItem(0)

        val profilePictureView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                                                        .inflate(R.layout.profile_image_layout,
                                                                 coordinator_main,
                                                                 false)
        menuItem?.actionView = profilePictureView

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this crash was using ActionMenuView as the root for my layout profile_image_layout and not setting it up correctly. Since I didn't really needed it, I switched to a different view class as root and the crashes are not happening anymore.